# How to cut alphanumeric string in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cut

I have a set of strings like "ABC-CDE-DEF-2023.03.14" or "ABD-DFS-FGD-F-2023.04.12" etc. I want to separate them as below:

> a=ABC-CDE-DEF  b=2023.03.14
>
> a=ABD-DFS-FGD-F b=2023.04.12

I am able to achieve it using awk, but want a solution other than sed, awk usage.

Comment: c.f. [basic bash parameter expansion rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for good string parsing tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, in `bash` it would be

```
str="ABC-CDE-DEF-2023.03.14"

a=${str%-[0-9]*}
b=${str##*[A-Z]-}

echo $a
ABC-CDE-DEF
echo $b
2023.03.14
```

Since you put `cut` as tag in your question:

```
echo $str | rev |cut -d- -f 2- | rev
echo $str | rev |cut -d- -f 1 | rev
```

would also work.

Comment: one-liner `var=ABC-CDE-DEF-2023.03.14; echo "a=${var%-[0-9]*} b=${var##*[A-Z]-}"`

Comment: With cut, you can use `-f -3` for `ABC-CDE-DEF`, but wouldn't work on `ABD-DFS-FGD-F` which adds an additional field. The parameter expansions work regardless.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, hm. Missed the extra field. `rev` should solve that.

Comment: Or easier solution : `a=${string%-*} b=${string##*-}.`

Answer (score 2):

I assume, *"last `-`"* is the key item to split and to be replaced by  `b=`.

```
#!/bin/sh

input="ABC-CDE-DEF-2023.03.14"
echo "a=${input%-*} b=${input##*-}"
```

Answer (score 2):

One possibility might be

```
for str in "ABC-CDE-DEF-2023.03.14" "ABD-DFS-FGD-F-2023.04.12"; do
    b=${str##*-}
    a=${str%-*}
    echo "a=$a b=$b"
done
```

Or, using `bash`'s conditional construct `[[…]]` and regular expression operator `=~`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for str in "ABC-CDE-DEF-2023.03.14" "ABD-DFS-FGD-F-2023.04.12"; do
    [[ $str =~ (.*)-(.*) ]]
    a=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    b=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    echo "a=$a b=$b"
done
```

Note: `bash`'s conditional construct `[[…]]` and regular expression operator `=~` may not work in POSIX `sh`.